# Why it is the type/size of the conditional operator?

Tags: c, sizeof, conditional-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    short int i = 2;
    float f = 3;
    if (sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(float))
        printf("float\n");
    else if (sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(short int))
        printf("short int\n");
    return 0;
}
```

can anyone please help me with this question why it is printing float  and why it is giving 4 for the sizeof(x==2) and can anyone help me with the flowchart ??
how ''' sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(float) ''' this code is giving true or 1 in if section ??

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Any specific compiler flags being used during compilation?

Comment: side note: there is no `sizeof(x==2)` in this code, there is `sizeof(result of ternary operator)`

Comment: The type of this expression `(x == 2) ? f : i` is the common type of `f` and `i`, which is `float`, so it's the same as `sizeof(float)` or `sizeof(f)` no matter the value of `x`.

Comment: The code is buggy. The result of `? f : i` is always float.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @273K: It is not buggy. The purpose of the code is to demonstrate that the type of the result of the conditional operator is a function of the second and third operand types. That is, it does not depend on the value of the first operand. The code serves that purpose, so it is not buggy.

Comment: @Eric If it was true, then the condition `x == 2` would be just non-distracting `false`.

Comment: how  ''' sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(float) ''' this code is giving true or 1 in if section

Comment: `sizeof` is calculated at compile time, so the result can't possibly be based on the condition part of the conditional operator.

Comment: @ikegami: `sizeof` may be computed at execution time. In `int n; scanf("%d", &n); int a[n]; printf("%zu\n", sizeof a);`, `sizeof a` is computed during execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is written to demonstrate how the type of the result of the conditional operator is determined.

If the result type depended on which of the second and third operands were selected by the first operand, then the type of `(x == 2) ? f : i` would be `float` or `short int`, depending on `x == 2`. Since, in this example, `x == 2` is false, it would be `short int`. However, execution of the code shows this is not the case, assuming that `float` has four bytes and `short int` has two bytes, as is common in current C implementations.

In `(x == 2) ? f : i`, `x == 2` is false (because the value of `x` is 1), so the result value is the value of `i`. However, the test `sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(float)` yields true, showing that, even though `i` is selected for the result value, the result type has the size of `float`, not the size of `short int`.

The rule for determining the result type of the conditional operator is in C 2018 6.5.15 5. For arithmetic operands, it says “the result type that would be determined by the usual arithmetic conversions, were they applied to those two operands, is the type of the result.” The *usual arithmetic conversions* are specified in C 2018 6.3.1.8. For `float` and `short int`, they produce `float`. So a conditional operator with `float` and `short int` for its second and third operands has result type `float`.

Comment: why result type has the size of float instead of short int ??

Comment: @premdanav: The answer states where the rules are. “C 2018” means the 2018 version of [the C standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) The type of the result of the conditional operator is determined at compile time from the types of the second and third operands. It has nothing to do with the value of the first operand. When you combine `float` and `short int` in an expression, as in `f + i`, the result type is `float`.

Comment: Worth noting that "the usual arithmetic conversations" is a very specific term defined by the C standard - there is a section in the standard that precisely defines what exactly the usual arithmetic conversions are.